# jQuery animation with knockout beforeAdd and afterRemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I wan't to animate tabs divs. When closing, the width is animated to 0px, and when opening, it is animated from 0px to the size of it's inner content.

https://jsfiddle.net/rrfogrku/5/

but the expected behaviour not work, closed div are not removed from DOM after the fadeOut function is called, and when I add a new tab, there is no animation.

Html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="tab-list">
        <!-- ko foreach: {data: editors, afterAdd: fadeIn, beforeRemove: fadeOut} -->
            <div class="tab" data-bind="
                css: { active: isSelected }, 
                click: $parent.select" >
                <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.close">x</button>
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <div class="plus">
            <button data-bind="click: add">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function MainViewModel() { 
        var self = this; 
        var storage = localStorage; 
        self.editors = ko.observableArray([new EditorViewModel("default.txt", "some content")]); 

        self.close = function(item){
            self.editors.remove(item);
            if(self.editors().length == 0){
                self.add();
            }
            else if(!self.editors().some(val=>val.isSelected())){
                self.select(self.editors()[0]);
            }
        }
        self.select = function(item){
            for(var i in self.editors()){
                self.editors()[i].isSelected(false);
            }
            item.isSelected(true); 
        }
        self.add = function(){
                var editor = new EditorViewModel("sans-titre.js", "");
                self.editors.push(editor);
                self.select(editor);
        }

        self.fadeIn = function(el){
            var $el = $(el);
            var w = $el.width();
            $el.css({ width: '0px' });
            $el.animate({width : w });
        }
        self.fadeOut = function(el){
            $(el).animate({ width: '0px'});
        }
        if(self.editors().length >0){
            self.select(self.editors()[0]);
        }
    }; 


    function EditorViewModel(title, initialContent){
        var self = this;
        self.title = ko.observable(title);
        self.content = ko.observable(initialContent);
        self.isSelected = ko.observable(false);
    }
    var viewModel = new MainViewModel(); 
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the example in the knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html), you can see that you need to check for the `nodeType` of the added element, since knockout can include multiple elements from the template and we're only interested in the `<div>`:

```
if (el.nodeType === 1) { /* do work */ }
```

[This page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) explains that, when using `beforeRemove`:

> Knockout cannot know how soon it is allowed to physically remove the DOM nodes (who knows how long your animation will take?), so it is up to you to remove them

So for your fade out animation, you'll have to add the code that updates the DOM:

```
$(el).animate({
  width: '0px'
}, 500, () => $(el).remove());
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- remove element after animation is done
```

Here's the two changes in an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lwfqpxk/

---

**Free bonus tip: add `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.tab` css to prevent the reflow during the width animation.**